# Fill columns with data via 2 defined parameters

Tags: r

I have a sample working data set (called `df`) which I have added columns to in `R`, and I would like to fill these columns with data according to very specific conditions.

I ran samples in a lab with 8 different variables, and always ran each sample with each variable twice (sample column).  From this, I calculated an average result, called `Cq_mean`.

The columns I have added in `R` below refer to each variable name.

I would like to fill these columns with `positive` or `negative` based on 2 conditions :

1. Variable
2. `Cq_mean`

As you see with my code below, I am able to create `positive` or `negative` results based on `Cq_mean`, however this logically runs it over the entire dataset, not taking into account variable as well, and it fills in cells with data that I would like to remain empty.  I am not sure how to ask `R` to take these two conditions into account at the same time.

positive: `Cq_mean <= 37.1`
negative: `Cq_mean >= 37`

**Helpful information:**

Under `sample`, the data is always separated by a dash (-) with sample number in front, and variable name after. Somehow I need to isolate what comes after the dash.

Please refer to my desired results table to visualize what I am aiming for.

```
df <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/ZPJS9Vjg", header=T,sep="")
```

add column names respective to variables

```
df$TypA <- ""
df$TypB <- ""
df$TypC <- ""
df$RP49 <- ""
df$RPS5 <- ""
df$H20 <- ""
df$F1409B <-""
df$F1430A <- ""
```

fill columns with data

```
df$TypA <- ifelse(df$Cq_mean>=37.1,"negative", 'positive')
df$TypB <- ifelse(df$Cq_mean>=37.1,"negative", 'positive')
```

## and continue through with each variable

**desired results (subset of entire dataset done by hand in excel):**

```
desired_outcome <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/P3PPbiwr", header = T, sep="\t")
```

Comment: why don't you just write `ifelse(df$Cq_mean>=37.1,"negative", 'positive')`? I find this question very confusingly worded though, and cannot make sense of how you get to the output. the first df has over 1000 rows, but the second has 14?

Comment: hi

The desired result is just a subset I quickly selected and did by hand,  hence why there are only 14 rows.  I have clarified this in the question

Also, I appreciate your answer.  It simplifies how I have been trying to do this. 

However, do you know how I could I also attach the variable to code as a defining parameter? Example: TypA would only have positive or negative when written under the sample column (such as my desired result shows) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
df$TypA[grepl('TypA', df$sample1)] <- ifelse(df$Cq_mean[grepl('TypA', df$sample1)] >= 37.1, 
                                            'neg', 'pos')
```

You'll need to do this once per new column you want.

The `grepl` will filter out only the rows where your string of choice (here `TypA`) is present in the sample variable.

Comment: Hello

This does answer it.  I have never heard of the grepl function. 

This is exactly what I was looking for.  I have ran it over my full dataset and got my desired result.  I appreciate all your help

Comment: no problem. feel free to mark as an answer (selecting the tick below the upvote button) to help future users. both `grep` and `grepl` are useful to know. grep returns the index of a pattern match, grepl returns a logical vector of any match. can find more info using `?grep` and `?grepl`